# Unnecessary re-renders on react-leaflet choropleth map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, choropleth

First of all, I'm new to React and the whole Frontend thing, so this is probably something obvious.

I'm writing a simple choropleth map in React using react-leaflet, but I'm facing some performance issues.

My case is very similar to the one you can see here:

https://codepen.io/hazmi/pen/JjoyONo

If you add a `console.log` statement to the `style` method and check the console you can see that the style method is called for every feature on the map on every `mouseover` or `mouseout` event.

In my case it is even worse, as style is called twice for *every* feature on the map.

Unfortunately, this is a huge performance issue on bigger maps and also causes all kinds of side effects.

I assume the style method is called because the `<GeoJSON>` layer is re-rendered all the time because of the state change caused by the 2 mouse event handlers setting the `selected` variable. My case is very similar, just the component structure is a bit more complex.

More components rely on the value of the `selected` variable, so I need that to be set on hover and reset on mouseout.

```
const colors = [ /* constant array */ ];

function Map() {

    const [hoveredCountry, setHoveredCountry] = useState(null);
    const [statsData, setStatsData] = useState(null);

...

    const highlightFeature = e => {
        let layer = e.target;
        setHoveredCountry({ stats: statsData[layer.feature.properties.iso_a3] });
    }

    const resetHighlight = e => {
        setHoveredCountry(null);
    }

    const onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight
        });
    }

    const style = feature => { /* calculate and return style object */ }

...

    return (
        <MapContainer center={[40, 0]}>
            <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' />
            <ZoomControl position='bottomleft' />
            <GeoJSON data={countries} style={style} onEachFeature={onEachFeature} ref={geoJsonLayer}>
                <InfoTooltip scope={dataScope} hoveredCountry={hoveredCountry} />
            </GeoJSON>
            <InfoBox data={selectedCountry} scope={dataScope} open={infoBoxOpen} closeHandler={handleInfoBoxClosed} />
            <MapControls options={dataScopes} value={dataScope} changeHandler={handleDataScopeChange} />
           <Legend scope={dataScope} colors={colors} hoveredCountry={hoveredCountry} />
        </MapContainer>
    );
}
```

In my case shown above, the `Legend` and `InfoTooltip` both depend on the `hoveredCountry` state variable similarly how the tooltip uses the `selected` state variable in the CodePen example.

How can I avoid these unnecessary re-renders? Is this the issue to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume the style method is called because the `<GeoJSON>` layer is re-rendered all the time because of the state change caused by the 2 mouse event handlers setting the selected variable.

You are on the right track indeed.

What happens is that React thinks it has to rerender that component because one of its props has changed:

```
<GeoJSON data={countries} style={style} onEachFeature={onEachFeature}>
```

Your `countries` variable (actually `data` in your CodePen) and `style` function are defined outside of your `App` component, so they are fine.

On the other hand, your `onEachFeature` function is declared *in the body* of your component. So everytime React reevaluates the component, and in particular whenever one of its state is changed, it reruns the `App` function, which creates a *new* `onEachFeature` function (which does exactly the same thing, but is is a different reference). Hence the `<GeoJSON>` component is rerendered.

And you had to keep it in there because it uses your state setter function.

A solution is simply to use the [`useCallback` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), which is made for such purpose: avoid a reference change whenever the component is reevaluated:

> This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders

In your case:

```
const onEachFeature = useCallback((feature, layer) => {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight
    });
}, []);
```

Note: inlining `highlightFeature` and `resetHighlight` would also make it clearer that you need them only when building the callback.

Comment: Hey @ghybs, thanks for your detailed answer! I've tried it but it did not help. I have modified the onEachFeature as you have suggested, but then I got an issue that `statsData` which is another state variable is missing, so I had to add that to the dependencies array of useCallback. Now the functionality works as before, but the style function is getting called just as much as before too.

Comment: Btw `style` is defined inside the component, if I use useCallback on that too it gets a bit better, now only 1 style method is called for each feature on mouse events not 2. The direction is good, but something is still missing.

Comment: Your description sounds different from what you have shared in your CodePen, so I am not sure if what I have seen is related to your exact issue. I also did not pay attention, but your CodePen actually uses React Leaflet version 2, which behaves differently from version 3. In version 2, if `style` is a function, it will be called everywhere everytime. But this may not be the reason for your performance issue, since your description sounds different from the CodePen. So even fixing the style may not help. Try using a fixed style first, and see if your issue persists.

Comment: You are right, sorry I'm not a 100% sure which aspects are important. I can't share the exact code, but I have created a very similar simplified one, which is available here: https://github.com/Timester/tmsvr-blog/tree/react-performance/react-choropleth-map It uses useCallback for both style and onEachFeature, and still on both mouse events call style for 230 features. The map itself is in here https://github.com/Timester/tmsvr-blog/blob/react-performance/react-choropleth-map/src/ChoroplethMap.jsx